# Adding css class dynamically using KockoutJS

Tags: javascript, css, html, mvvm, knockout.js

Hi wonder if someone can help, I'm relatively new to KnockoutJS. I have a class called green-bar which I need to make active when two states are true. Please can someone help me. My solution below doesn't work - not sure where I'm going wrong:

```
<div class="content" data-bind="css: { 'green-bar': isBusy() && !isComplete() }">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my solution was working but was located outside the binding area.